# 'GIS' grade mobile mapping app that isnt ArcPad?

Tags: android, mobile, mapping, ipad

I am a GIS analyst/geologist with a mining company based in Canada. However most of my fieldwork is in remote places with minimal access to the internet. I am after a reliable alternative to ArcPad and ESRI running on either ipad or android tablets. I have already tried several apps like Mapitfast and cartomobile but Ive been unimpressed with either their UI and/or inability to share/access data off the device.

Some tools I need are:

- Creating rock outcrop maps
- Editing/importing geology polygons
- GPS tracking that can be exported for later use
- Photo-tagging would be a plus
- Bing or Google as a background image

Thanks in advance.

-David-

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [Mappt](http://www10.giscafe.com/nbc/articles/1/1182821/Mappt-new-Android-app-mapping-data-collection)? I read an article about it on GIS Cafe a couple of weeks ago.
On their website it says they recommend the new Samsung Nexus so I am waiting on getting mine before testing Mappt out.